# Can't POST or DELETE with app.all, only GET works

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.all('/test', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('hit');
    res.send('send')
})
```

If I hit this route with GET via Postman, it logs and sends the value, if I switch to POST it fails with a 404, what's going on? I know there's not much info but is there any rational reason this may happen before I try and include more code? Thanks

Update: Looks like it's the Lusca middleware:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   lusca.csrf()(req, res, next);
});
```

Considering conditionally skipping certain routes to prevent this

Comment: I think we will need to see more code.  There must be something else interacting with this causing your problem.

Comment: Maybe you have another middleware preventing all non GET verbs. we need more code.

Comment: Antoine, it's kind of hard to help here when you aren't responding.  Please don't just disappear after posting.  Your rep implies you've been around here enough to know that you get a lot better service if you're around after posting to address questions that arise and engage the people who are trying to help.

Comment: Sorry I had to run some errands, I just got back and am debugging right now @jfriend00

Comment: Well, better to post when you can be around for at least the next 20-30 mins.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the ***shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself***. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your question is missing the part in bold.

Comment: Updated now @jfriend00

Comment: The protocol here is if you figure out an answer to your own question, then, if you think it might be useful to others, you can post an answer to your own question.  If it probably isn't useful to others, you can just delete the question.  In any case, answers should **not** be put into your question.  If you have a lead as to what is causing it, but haven't fully figure it out yet, you can put that info in a comment.

Comment: @jfriend00 Once I get something working I will add the solution as an answer